# ps/image-optimizer Showing psr/log installation error with laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-5.7

I am trying to install ps/image-optimizer in laravel 5.7 but its showing psr/log error and not supporting latest psr/log package.

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for ps/image-optimizer ^1.2 -> satisfiable by ps/imag   e-optimizer[1.2.0].
    - Conclusion: remove psr/log 1.1.0
    - Conclusion: don't install psr/log 1.1.0
    - ps/image-optimizer 1.2.0 requires psr/log 1.0.* -> satisfiable by psr/log[1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: psr/log[1.0.0, 1.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: psr/log[1.0.1, 1.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: psr/log[1.0.2, 1.1.0].
    - Installation request for psr/log (locked at 1.1.0) -> satisfiable by psr/log[1.1.0].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

[ps/image-optimizer](https://packagist.org/packages/ps/image-optimizer)

Comment: exception showing everything. remove psr log 1.1.0 and then install 1.0.0 . after that install image optimizer package

Comment: Edit your composer.json to downgrade psr/log to version 1.0 or contact ps/imageoptimizer developer to update its psr/log to newer version

Comment: i tried to downgrade but i want to use latest version of psr/log. how can i change the dependencies of this package?